# google load balancing external ip

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I am trying to setup Google Compute Load Balancer to HTTP content route between my Google Compute Machines and my appEngine application, depending on the URL.

I can get everything setup but it appears right now I can only route to InstanceGroups, which must be made up on GoogleCompute VM's.

It seems strange to me that I cannot route to external IP's to Google Compute VM's (appEngine or otherwise)

Is this a limitation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, [Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) only provides global load balancing for HTTP(S) requests destined for Compute Engine VM instances.

Google App Engine has its own way of the [scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability).

Nevertheless, if you see adding support of App Engine to HTTP(S) load balancer could be a useful feature, feel free to open a feature request on [Google Compute Engine issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list).

Comment: Is there any workaround? Is it possible to forward some traffic to a GAE instance based on a url pattern?